# CakePHP and EasyPHP

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, http-status-code-404, easyphp

I'm new in PHP and I'm facing some problems.

I'm using EasyPHP (DevServer 14.1 -> PHP 5.5.8 and Apache 2.4.7) and CakePHP (2.5.1).

Well, if I put the CakePHP files at "C:\Program Files\EasyPHP\data\localweb\" (then it would be "C:\Program Files\EasyPHP\data\localweb\cake_2_0..." for example), it works fine, as it should.

The problem is: I would like to use alias on EasyPHP, for I don't want to develop at "C:\Program Files...". But when I put the CakePHP files on my application root ("C:\myapps\myproject..." for example, with an alias set on EasyPHP), then I get a "Error 404". Now, I found that if I remove the .htaccess file from root, it works. But I'm sure this file is there for some reason, so I don't feel right just removing it - it might give me more problems later.

Does anyone know anything about it? Can I use alias on EasyPHP if I want to use CakePHP?
Thanks in advance.

***Edited***

This is my apache_alias.conf (C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\conf):

```
Alias "/cakeblogtutorial" "C:/Programacao/PHP/workspace/CakeBlogTutorial"
<Directory "C:/Programacao/PHP/workspace/CakeBlogTutorial">
Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
AllowOverride All
Order deny,allow
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Deny from all
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

This is my .htaccess (C:\Programacao\PHP\workspace\CakeBlogTutorial):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

On my httpd.conf (C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\binaries\conf_files), regarding to mod_rewrite (in other words, uncommented):

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Last lines on error.log (C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\binaries\apache\logs):

```
[Mon Jun 02 14:27:48.093057 2014] [:error] [pid 4284:tid 848] [client 127.0.0.1:62831] script 'C:/Program Files/EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11/data/localweb/index.php' not found or unable to stat
[Mon Jun 02 14:34:59.319532 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1992:tid 312] AH00424: Parent: Received restart signal -- Restarting the server.
[Mon Jun 02 14:34:59.982390 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1992:tid 312] AH00455: Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) PHP/5.5.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jun 02 14:34:59.982390 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1992:tid 312] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Nov 21 2013 20:13:01
[Mon Jun 02 14:34:59.982390 2014] [core:notice] [pid 1992:tid 312] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\EASYPH~1.1VC\\binaries\\apache\\bin\\eds-httpd.exe -d C:/Program Files/EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11/binaries/apache'
[Mon Jun 02 14:34:59.988391 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1992:tid 312] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 6588
[Mon Jun 02 14:35:01.279844 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6588:tid 364] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Mon Jun 02 14:35:01.523147 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4284:tid 364] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
```

Last lines on access.log (C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\binaries\apache\logs):

```
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jun/2014:15:09:50 -0300] "GET /cakeblogtutorial HTTP/1.1" 301 242
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jun/2014:15:09:50 -0300] "GET /cakeblogtutorial/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1156
```

Comment: Your 404 should have a description at apache's log so to understand what went wrong. You also don't show your alias configuration file, don't say if you enabled mod_rewrite, if you checked permissions, it can be lots of things.

Comment: @user221931 I added some more information, as you suggested. Do you have any clue now? I really know almost nothing about configuration...

Comment: This helps but it doesn't look like a misconfiguration error of apache. Please add the application's log (``C:/Programacao/PHP/workspace/CakeBlogTutorial/tmp/log/error.log``) in your message.

Comment: @user221931 File error.log (C:\Programacao\PHP\workspace\CakeBlogTutorial\app\tmp\logs) is empty. I've been looking for answers, and I found a suggestion to a similar error, to put the line RewriteBase /cakeblogtutorial on .htaccess file. I've tried, and it worked. But again, I'm not sure is the right thing to do. I'm happy I found a way on wich it works, but not satisfied 'cause it can get wrong again later.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the correct Windows directory path contains a backslash.  <Directory "C:\Programacao\PHP\workspace\CakeBlogTutorial">

Comment: But that was automatically generated, so I suppose is correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I found the answer - and if so, the `RewriteBase` is the correct thing to do. From the CakePHP WebSite (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html):

> For many hosting services (GoDaddy, 1and1), your web server is actually being served from a user directory that already uses mod_rewrite. If you are installing CakePHP into a user directory (http://example.com/~username/cakephp/), or any other URL structure that already utilizes mod_rewrite, you’ll need to add RewriteBase statements to the .htaccess files CakePHP uses (/.htaccess, /app/.htaccess, /app/webroot/.htaccess).